# asp.net identity mvc FirstOrDefaultAsync method not found

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

VS2017 Pro, project - asp.net web app .net 4.6 (mvc template) individual user account authentication.

When i try to register new user i get exception -

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> Method not found: 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1<!!0>
>   System.Data.Entity.QueryableExtensions.FirstOrDefaultAsync(System.Linq.IQueryable`1,
>   System.Linq.Expressions.Expression`1<System.Func`2>)'. 
>   Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.MissingMethodException: Method not found:
>   'System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1<!!0>
>   System.Data.Entity.QueryableExtensions.FirstOrDefaultAsync(System.Linq.IQueryable`1,
>   System.Linq.Expressions.Expression`1<System.Func`2>)'.
>
> Source Error:
>
> Line 155: var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user,
>   model.Password);

Does anyone know how to solve this ?

Project: https://github.com/BobaFett58/MoshHamedani

[Error img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AxTDy.png)

Comment: Check your references. See also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28206109/1260204,

Comment: Check your references. I'm assuming the System.Data.Entity.dll didn't get copied into the bin.

Comment: I managed to create a new user, try to delete bin and obj folder and rebuild, if it doesn't help, try to delete all temporary files related to .net

Comment: @Igor all my references to .net45 and it's doesn't work.

Comment: @Dispersia , i added System.Data.Entity.dll to references and it doesn't help. :\

Comment: @RickyStam , i deleted files from c:\Users\[youruserid]\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files , bin and obj and it's doesn't help :|

Comment: Try also to delete the temporary files from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files

Comment: @RickyStam its empty :)

Comment: @DenysZorin and copy local is true for all of your references?